# piping a string to gcc with python's subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux, gcc

I have a c++ style text file that I'm trying to pipe to gcc to remove the comments. Initially, I tried a regex approach, but had trouble handling things like nested comments, string literals and EOL issues.

So now I'm trying to do something like:

```
strip_comments(test_file.c)

def strip_comments(text):
    p = Popen(['gcc', '-w', '-E', text], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    p.stdin.write(text)
    p.stdin.close()
    print p.stdout.read()
```

but instead of passing the file, I'd like to pipe the contents because the files I'm trying to preprocess don't actually have the .c extension

Has anyone had any success with anything like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works with `subprocess.PIPE` (os.popen() is deprecated), and you also need to pass and additional `-` argument to gcc to make it process stdin:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def strip_comments(text):
    p = Popen(['gcc', '-fpreprocessed', '-dD', '-E', '-x', 'c++', '-'], 
            stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    p.stdin.write(text)
    p.stdin.close()
    return_code = p.wait()
    print p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed the - argument

Comment: updated with the arguments from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394017/remove-comments-from-c-c-code

Comment: Even better! Thank you again