# C Program won't remove comments that take up the whole line

Tags: c

So I'm working through the K&R C book and there was a bug in my code that I simply cannot figure out.

The program is supposed to remove all the comments from a C program. Obviously I'm just using stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getaline (char s[], int lim);

#define MAXLINE 1000 //maximum number of characters to put into string[]

#define OUTOFCOMMENT 0
#define INASINGLECOMMENT 1
#define INMULTICOMMENT 2

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int isInComment;
    char string[MAXLINE];

    getaline(string, MAXLINE);

    for (i = 0; string[i] != EOF; ++i) {
        //finds whether loop is in a comment or not
        if (string[i] == '/') {
            if (string[i+1] == '/')
                isInComment = INASINGLECOMMENT;
            if (string[i+1] == '*')
                isInComment = INMULTICOMMENT;
        }
        //fixes the problem of print messing up after the comment
        if (isInComment == INASINGLECOMMENT && string[i] == '\0')
            printf("\n");

        //if the line is done, restates all the variables
        if (string[i] == '\0') {
            getaline(string, MAXLINE);
            i = 0;
            if (isInComment != INMULTICOMMENT)
                isInComment = OUTOFCOMMENT;
        }

        //prints current character in loop
        if(isInComment == OUTOFCOMMENT && string[i] != EOF)
            printf("%c", string[i]);

        //checks to see of multiline comment is over
        if(string[i] == '*' && string[i+1] == '/' ) {
            ++i;
            isInComment = OUTOFCOMMENT;
        }

    }
    return 0;

}
```

So this works great except for one problem. Whenever a line starts with a comment, it prints that comment.

So for instance, if I had a line that was simply

```
//this is a comment
```

without anything before the comment begins, it will print that comment even though it's not supposed to.

I thought I was making good progress, but this bug has really been holding me up. I hope this isn't some super easy thing I've missed.

EDIT: Forget the getaline function

```
//puts line into s[], returns length of that line
int getaline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim-1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: What's in "getaline" function?

Comment: `string[i] != EOF` doesn't seem right. I think it should be `string[i] != '\0'`

Comment: `string[i] != EOF;` --> `string[i] !=  0;` for a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

- `isInComment` is not initialized in function `main`.
- as pointed by others, `string[i] != EOF` is wrong.  You need to test for end of file more precisely, especially for files that do not end with a linefeed. This test only works if `char` type is signed and `EOF` is a valid `signed char` value. It will nonetheless mistakenly stop on a stray `\377` character, which is legal in a string or in a comment.
- When you detect the end of line, you read another line and reset `i` to `0`, but i will be incremented by the for loop *before* you test again for single line comment... hence the bug!
- You do not handle special cases such as `/* // */`  or `// /*`
- You do not handle strings.  This is not a comment: `"/*"`, nor this: `'//'`
- You do not handle `\` at end of line (escaped linefeed).  This can be used to extend single line comments, strings, etc.  There are more subtle cases related to `\` handling and if you really want completeness, you should handle trigraphs too.
- Your implementation has a limit for line size, this is not needed.

The problem you are assigned is a bit tricky. Instead of reading and parsing lines, read one character at a time and implement a state machine to parse escaped linefeeds, strings, and both comment styles.  The code is not too difficult if you do it right with this method.

Comment: Dang. I need to work on my code. Thanks for pointing out all the faults.

Comment: Is it normal to suck this badly at first? Very discouraging.

Comment: Don't worry about this, the problem you are tackling is actually quite difficult.  There is a duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238390/remove-all-comments-from-a-c-program-any-possible-improvements-to-this-code?rq=1 but they don't get it right either.

Answer (score 4):

```
    if (string[i] == '\0') {
        getaline(string, MAXLINE);
        i = 0;
        if (isInComment != INMULTICOMMENT)
            isInComment = OUTOFCOMMENT;
    }
```

When you start a new line, you initialize `i` to 0. But then in the next iteration:

```
for (i = 0; string[i] != EOF; ++i)
```

`i` will be incremented, so you'll begin the new line with index `1`. Therefore there is a bug when the line begins with `//`.

You can see that it solves the problem if you write instead:

```
    if (string[i] == '\0') {
        getaline(string, MAXLINE);
        i = 0;
        if (isInComment != INMULTICOMMENT)
            isInComment = OUTOFCOMMENT;
    }
```

though it's usually considered as bad style to modify `for` loop indices inside the loop. You may redesign your implementation in a more readable way.