# In vim, how to remove all the C and C++ comments?

Tags: c, vim, comments

How to remove all C and C++ comments in vi?

```
//

/*       
 */
```

Comment: I would suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53551634/3625404). (I wrote it to use inside vim.)

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Parsing C and C++ comments is not something that regular expressions can do. It might work for simple cases, but you never know if the result leaves you with a corrupted source file. E.g. what happens to this:

```
 printf ("//\n");
```

The proper way is to use an external tool able to parse C. For example some compilers may have an option to strip comments.

Writing a comment stripper is also a basic exercise in lex and yacc programming.

See also this question: [Remove comments from C/C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394017/remove-comments-from-c-c-code)

Answer (score 4):

With regular expressions, because of the complexity of C/C++ syntax, you will at best achieve a solution that is 90% correct. Better let the right tool (a compiler) do the job.

Fortunately, Vim integrates nicely with external tools. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394040/813602), you can do:

```
:%! gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E "%" 2>/dev/null
```

Caveats:

- requires `gcc`
- it also slightly modifies the formatting (shrunk indent etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Esc:%s/\/\///

Esc:%s/\/\*//

Esc:%s/\*\///
```

Comment: apart from what would your command do, you can use `#,@...` as separator for `:s`, if pattern contains `/` ... and your commands are not answers to this question.

Comment: What does this do to `printf ("//\n");`?

Comment: Jens... Yes... I agree that it will remove the // in printf statement too

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lexical analyzer like [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) directly applied to source codes. In its manual you can find "[How can I match C-style comments?](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/How-can-I-match-C_002dstyle-comments_003f.html)".

If you need an in-depth tutorial, you can find it [here](http://home.deib.polimi.it/scandale/?p=/content/teaching/2013/lfc); under "Lexical Analysis" section you can find a pdf that introduce you to the tool and an archive with some practical examples, including "c99-comment-eater".