# Deleting multiple types of comments with sed command

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, comments

I have a directory of C files. I want to remove all types of comments from these source files.

For example, let's say I have a source code that is similar to the following file.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {   
 int number;
 /* Sample Multiline Comment 
 * Line 1
 * Line 2
 */
 printf("Enter an integer: ");  

 // reads and stores input
 scanf("%d", &number);
 printf("You entered: %d", number); //display output 

 return 0;
 /* Comment */
}
```

I want to remove all types of comments in this code. This includes,

```c
//    
/* */   
/*
*
*/
```

I have attempted to carry out this task by using a sed command.

```
find . -type f |xargs sed -i 's,/\*\*,,g;s,\*/,,g;s,/\*,,g;s,//,,g'
```

This only removes the above comment symbols itself but not the comment. I would like to remove the entire comment along with the above three comment symbols.

How can I achieve this criteria.

Comment: IMHO I don't think any other tool is good for this task, this may lead to False Positives too. So better why not use something in that language itself I googles and found one link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-comments-given-cc-program/  take a look if this helps you?

Comment: @coder: Did you think of statements such as `strcpy(s, "// this is not a comment")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove comments from C/C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394017/remove-comments-from-c-c-code)

Answer (score 0):

Approach this from two perspectives.

1. You delete a line that starts with your matching criteria
2. You delete content that starts with some criteria and ends with different criteria.

To delete a line that starts with criteria:

`sed '/^\/\// d'`

To delete between a start and finish use:

`sed 's/\/\*.*\*\/://'`

Warning.  Be careful when you have other lines that may start with the applicable characters.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't do the trick for me. I ran the following command with your code,   find . -type f |xargs sed -i '/^\/\// d' However, it shows no effect.

Comment: @agent82 : Be careful when doing this line-oriented. A C-program may have a logical line spanning several physical lines, by ending a line with a backslash.

Comment: What about find .. -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/^\/\// d' .    Also try to use the sed command on a cat of one file first to make sure it does what you want before you daisychain it to a find.

Comment: @agent82 no it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a time-pass try with `awk`, but maybe it helps:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash    

awk '
    function remove_comments(line)
    {
        # multi-line comment is active, clear everything
        if (flag_c == 1) {

            if (sub(/.*[*][\/]$/, "", line)) {
                flag_c=0
            }
            else {
                # skip this line
                # its all comment
                return 1
            }

        }

        # remove multi-line comments(/**/) made on the same line
        gsub(/[\/][*].*[*][\/]/, "", line)

        # remove single line comments if any
        sub(/[\/][\/].*$/, "", line)

        # make flag_c=1 if a multi-line comment has been started
        if (sub(/[\/][*].*/, "", line))
        {
            flag_c=1
        }

        return line
    }

    ##
    #   MAIN
    ##
    {
        $0 = remove_comments($0)

        if ($0 == 1 || $0 == "")
            next

        print
    }
' file.c
```

Comment: Sorry for being nickpicking but it fails for the statement such as `printf("http://www.foo.bar");`
I'm afraid we cannot remove comments robustly without a parser for the language.

Comment: @tshiono, yes that makes sense. The script would consider `//` in the string a comment. Agreed, a parser that knows about the language is much reliable!

Answer (score 0):

You are best off using the C preprocessor for this, as in the answer for [Remove comments from C/C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394017/remove-comments-from-c-c-code).

You can ask the preprocessor to remove comments by running `gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E foo.c`.

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 int number;
 /* Sample Multiline Comment
 * Line 1
 * Line 2
 */
 printf("Enter an integer: ");

 // reads and stores input
 scanf("%d", &number);
 printf("You entered: %d", number); //display output

 return 0;
 /* Comment */
}
$ gcc -fpreprocessed -dD -E foo.c
# 1 "foo.c"
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 int number;




 printf("Enter an integer: ");


 scanf("%d", &number);
 printf("You entered: %d", number);

 return 0;

}
```