# Removing comments with unix from sql file

Tags: sed

Having a sql file (package), I want to remove all the comments (`/*text*/`) from the file with UNIX (`sed`).
This is what I have tried:

`sed 's/[:blank:]*-~.*[\n]*.*~-$//' file.txt`

It seems that the line feed character does not work that way. Any suggestions?
It should remove from line 3 to 8. And line 15.

**SQL File:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MYSCHEMA.MYPACKAGE
AS
/***************************************************************************
    Author         : myname
    Date 10/2019
    Overview       : This is the main control procedure
   Major Modifications (initial, when, ver, irfs, description):
***************************************************************************/
PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE (p_error        IN OUT   NUMBER,
                                        p_return_code     IN OUT   NUMBER,
                                        p_error_message   IN OUT   VARCHAR2)
AS
v_infomsgid             NUMBER;
BEGIN
/*This is my comment about this process*/
   MY_SQL_CODE_HERE;
END;
END MYPACKAGE;
```

The desired output is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MYSCHEMA.MYPACKAGE
AS
PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE (p_error        IN OUT   NUMBER,
                                        p_return_code     IN OUT   NUMBER,
                                        p_error_message   IN OUT   VARCHAR2)
AS
v_infomsgid             NUMBER;
BEGIN
   MY_SQL_CODE_HERE;
END;
END MYPACKAGE;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Doing it with `sed` is almost impossible, because regex is greedy and there are no lookarounds. Lines like `/* comment */ code /* comment */` are going to be hard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove comments from C/C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394017/remove-comments-from-c-c-code)

Comment: If you want to remove `/text/` then those from your example is a problem: `10/2019`.

Comment: @Cyrus I edited the question, OP did not use backquotes around `/*text*/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the link @KamilCuk gave in a comment for dedicated tools or use `GNU sed`:

```
sed -z 's#\*/#\r#g;s#/\*[^\r]*\r\n*##g' file.txt
```

Explanation:
First replace `*/` with a unique character (I will use `\r`, because you should already have removed the Windows line endings). Next you can remove the comment.
Using option `-z` is for matching comments that last more than 1 line, and removing the newline after the end of a comment.