# Is there a way to automatically uppercase comments in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

Is there a way to automatically uppercase comments in Xcode? Either when typing individual comments or globally after the fact?

Comment: For the latter, Caps Lock? (zing!)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Ben why zing? that's a legit answer!

Comment: WHY WOULD YOU WANT TO DO THAT!

Comment: thanks, I realize that a lot of people tend to find all caps annoying.  I personally find it easier to read my code/comments when they're in caps.

@Ben: touché.  I actually got a chuckle out of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the WHY WOULD YOU WANT TO DO THAT?! question:

There is nothing built into Xcode to do this for you.

I would start with a script designed to do something similar like strip out C comments from code [Python snippet to remove C and C++ comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241327/python-snippet-to-remove-c-and-c-comments) is a good starting point. Then adapt that to write a new file with your special comments.

Answer (score 0):

You're never the only one  . . . You can go into Preferences-Fonts & Colors and then choose a font that has only caps (ex. Copperplate).

[image]