# how to find '/*N*/ ' using regexp

Tags: regex, comments

I don't want to learn regexps only for this particular problem.
I need to find some '/*N*/ ' comments through C++ files.
Can someone write a regexp which finds such comments?

Comment: You do want or don't want RegExp?

Comment: don't want to learn :) sorry for that mistake

Comment: Are you literally looking for N, or is N the actual comment text?

Comment: `\/\*N\*\/` - and don't tag the question with `c++` if it is actually a `regex` problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python snippet to remove C and C++ comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241327/python-snippet-to-remove-c-and-c-comments)

Comment: @KennyTM -1: yes, everyone has python installed and already knows what a hell scripts are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex :

```
/\/\*(.*?)\*\//
```

This is how it works :

```
\/    <- The / character (escaped because I used / as a delimiter)
\*    <- The * character (escaped because it's a special character)
(     <- Start of a group
  .     <- Any character
  *     <- Repeated but not mandatory
  ?     <- Lazy matching
)     <- End of the group
\*    <- The * character
\/    <- The / character
```

Edit : It doesn't handle `\n` nor `\r\n`, if you want it to then consider [@Alex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933990/how-to-find-n-using-regexp/3934029#3934029) with the `m` flag.

Comment: +1 (although I considered downvoting: The OP doesn't want to learn Regexps :-P )

Comment: I didn't say I don't want an explanation :D

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
/\/\*(.+?)\*\//m
```

`$1` will be your comments.

Hopefully `m` pattern modifier will make the period (match all) match new lines (`\n`) as well.

Note the `+` means it will only match comments with at least one character - since it seems you want to know the comments themselves, this is OK (what use will 0 length comment be)?

However, if you want to know the total comment blocks, change the `+` (1 or more) to `*` (0 or more).

Also, why not give regex a try? It is tricky at the start because the syntax looks funny, but they are really powerful.

Answer (score 0):

How about: (?<=\/*)(.*?)(?=*\/)

Which uses lookbehinds and lookaheads and captures the comment text (otherwise remove the parens around the .*, not to capture). Make sure you use a multi-line search, because these are multi-line comments