# json.loads function doesn't receive proper JSON - EXCEPTION: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)

Tags: json, exception, curl

I am on Windows 7 and my curl expression is as follows:

curl --header "X-CSRFToken: csrftoken" -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" -d "{"username":"Steven"}"

However an exception is thrown at

```
simplejson.loads(request.body)
```

presumably because the json.loads function doesn't receive proper JSON.

It reads: Caught Exception: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033633/handling-lazy-json-in-python-expecting-property-name)

Try this: `"{"username":"Steven"}"` change to `'{"username":"Steven"}'`