# Convert unicode string dictionary into dictionary in python

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary

I have unicode `u"{'code1':1,'code2':1}"` and I want it in dictionary format.

I want it in `{'code1':1,'code2':1}` format.

I tried `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', my_data).encode('ascii','ignore')` but it returns string not dictionary.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use built-in `ast` package:

```
import ast

d = ast.literal_eval("{'code1':1,'code2':1}")
```

Help on function literal_eval in module ast:

> literal_eval(node_or_string)
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Comment: if I have something like {u'a': {u'nstext': u'(Article)', u'title': u'article title', u'namespace': u'0', u'len': u'4339', u'touched': u'20140829055924', u'id': u'28621'}, u'n': u'page'} this answer gives me ValueError: malformed string

Comment: Getting an error when I try it (as usual, nothing works for me):  SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing,  File "<unknown>", line 1
    700 000
          ^

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza looks like there is a problem with your file, not with my answer. Don't see why would you need to downvote it, but it's up to you.

Comment: This is the code i ended up using looks like: data_meta = json.loads( str( myjsonstring ) )              Maybe your code isn't meant for strings but only for files.

Comment: OMG, I've been pulling my hair out looking for something like this!

Answer (score 16):

You can use `literal_eval`.  You may also want to be sure you are creating a dict and not something else.  Instead of `assert`, use your own error handling.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from collections import MutableMapping

my_dict = literal_eval(my_str_dict)
assert isinstance(my_dict, MutableMapping)
```

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT**: Turns out my assumption was incorrect; because the keys are not wrapped in double-quote marks ("), the string isn't JSON.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033633/handling-lazy-json-in-python-expecting-property-name) for some ways around this.

<s>I'm guessing that what you have might be [JSON](http://json.org/), a.k.a. JavaScript Object Notation.</s>

You can use Python's built-in `json` module to do this:

```
import json
result = json.loads(u"{'code1':1,'code2':1}")   # will NOT work; see above
```

Comment: Worked well in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting unicode error when I was reading a json from a file. So this one worked for me.

```
import ast
job1 = {}
with open('hostdata2.json') as f:
  job1= json.loads(f.read())

f.close()

#print type before converting this from unicode to dic would be <type 'unicode'>

print type(job1)
job1 =  ast.literal_eval(job1)
print "printing type after ast"
print type(job1)
# this should result <type 'dict'>

for each in job1:
 print each
print "printing keys"
print job1.keys()
print "printing values"
print job1.values()
```

Comment: When you have the `open()` statement in a `with`, there's no need to call the `close()` method -- it happens automatically once the `with` finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin `eval` function to convert the string to a python object

```
>>> string_dict = u"{'code1':1, 'code2':1}"
>>> eval(string_dict)
{'code1': 1, 'code2': 1}
```

Comment: As someone once told me, eval is evil.  Use literal_eval instead.

Comment: @pyrospade why so?

Comment: @Ishanmahajan, `eval()` offers no restrictions or protections on the code being executed.  For example it would happily use the `os` module to reorganize folders, delete files, etc.  This is a serious and dangerous security flaw.  `literal_eval` on the other hand is very tightly restricted.  It will only function on certain limited expressions which do not run the risk of affecting anything outside the app itself.