# TypeError misunderstanding

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert JSON to CSV. I got a "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

I looked at Q&As such as these: [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers), but I think I am understanding something wrongly.

Snippets of the JSON and code follows:

```
import csv
import json

x = """{"status": "user data saved", "lastupdate": "2015-04-24", "offeredBonus": true, "bround_rn": 19, "currenttrial": 30, "assignmentId": "abc", "workerId": "def", "condition": 1}"""
x = json.loads(x)
print x
f = csv.writer(open("tested.csv","wb+"))

# write CSV header
f.writerow(["worker_id","offeredBonus","trial","rewards"])

for a in x:
    print a, type(a) # for debugging
    print x, type(x) # for debugging
    f.writerow(a["status"])
    ...
```

It is the last line ("writerow") that gives me an error. Furthermore I notice that type(x) is a dictionary, but type(a) is unicode.

Does that mean I must use the ast package ([Convert unicode string dictionary into dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950260/convert-unicode-string-dictionary-into-dictionary-in-python)) to convert unicode into a dictionary, so I won't encounter the error? Or is there a simpler way out?

Comment: When you iterate over a dictionary you get the keys. Don't understand, what you try to do.

Comment: What is the output of `print a`?

Comment: The output is unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a dictionary, because that's what you get from the `json.loads()` call. When you do `for a in x`, you are given the *keys*. That's why you get that error: `a` is a string, ie the first key in `x`.

I think you are using the wrong data. It doesn't make sense to try and make a CSV of a single dictionary, because there's only one row. Perhaps you meant `x` to be a *list* of dictionaries?

```
x = """
[
    {"status": "user data saved", ...},
    {"status": "another_status", ...},
]
"""
```