# Dataframe from complex data structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I need to have data stored as follows:

```
[[[{}][{}]]]
```

or a list of lists of two lists of dictionaries

where:

`{}`: dictionaries containing data from individual frames observing an event. (There are two observers/stations, hence two dictionaries.)

`[{}][{}]`: two lists of all the individual frames related to a single event, one from each observer/station.

`[[{}][{}]]`: list of all events on a single night of observation.

`[[[{}][{}]]]`: list of all nights.

Hopefully that's clear. What I want to do is create two pandas dataframes where all dictionaries from `station_1` are stored in one, and all dictionaries from `station_2` are stored in the other.

My current method is as follows (where `data` is the above data structure):

```
for night in range(len(data)):

    station_1 = pd.DataFrame(data[night][0])
    station_2 = pd.DataFrame(data[night][1])

    all_station_1.append(station_1)
    all_station_2.append(station_2)

all_station_1 = pd.concat(all_station_1)
all_station_2 = pd.concat(all_station_2)
```

My understanding though is that the for loop must be horribly inefficient since I will be scaling the application of this script way up from my sample dataset this cost could easily become unmanageable.

So, any advice for a smarter way of proceeding would be appreciated! I feel like pandas is so user friendly there's gotta be an efficient way of dealing with any kind of data structure but I haven't been able to find it on my own yet. Thanks!

Comment: You could experiment with `pd.read_json()`.

Comment: an example with data in your `[[[{}][{}]]]` and expected dataframe would be useful to test

Comment: Sure, I've made a sample accessible here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8b4zqq6nhzbie4p/datasample.txt?dl=0

Comment: Not trying to be picky but this is too big to be easy to use (I would also need to parse out the file itself...). To understand more clearly, a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Working on reducing it now

Comment: Here's a reduced version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fn8d5yjlk9ak10/datasample2.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can really avoid using a loop here, unless you want to invoke jq via sh. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494030/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-deeply-nested-json)

Anyways, using your full sample, I managed to parse it into a multiindexed dataframe, which I assume is what you want.

```
import datetime
import re
import json

data=None
with open('datasample.txt', 'r') as f:
    data=f.readlines()
# There's only one line
data=data[0]

# Replace single quotes to double quotes: I did that in the .txt file itself, you could do it using re

# Fix the datetime problem
cleaned_data = re.sub(r'(datetime.datetime\(.*?\))', lambda x: '"'+ str(eval(x.group(0)).isoformat())+'"', data)
```

Now that the string from the file is valid json, we can load it:

```
json_data = json.loads(cleaned_data)
```

And we can process it into a dataframe:

```
# List to store the dfs before concat
all_ = []
for n, night in enumerate(json_data):
    for s, station in enumerate(night):
        events = pd.DataFrame(station)
        # Set index to the event number
        events = events.set_index('###')
        # Prepend night number and station number to index
        events.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(n, s, x) for x in events.index])
        all_.append(events)

df_all = pd.concat(all_)
# Rename the index levels
df_all.index.names = ['Night','Station','Event']
# Convert to datetime
df_all.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(df_all.DateTime)
df_all
```

(Truncated) Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I follow the majority of what's going on but would like to please ask two further questions:

1. What is the problem that you are fixing with datetime? I can maybe fix it at source since I have access to the script that is used to prepare the data files.
2. How can I replace the single quotes using re? I'm not sure how to avoid my quotes being interpreted as strings.

Thanks again!

Comment: It would help of you could format datetime in ISO format string initially. Here I have to eval the datetime.datime(...) into an ISO string for Json.  In your file there's `datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 13, 22, 15, 37, 880000)`, I convert that to `"2011-12-13T22:15:37.880000"
Also, JSON in strict form requires quotes to be double quotes " not single quotes ', so you could change that in your script to prepare the data. Otherwise you can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033633/handling-lazy-json-in-python-expecting-property-name) to do it in python after the fact.