# How to remove multi-line text pattern from all text files (recursively)?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to remove this pattern from all text files walking through the directories (recursively) with Windows batch script (.bat).

How to do that?

Here's a multi-line text pattern:

```
/* this is
a multi-line
pattern
*/
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove comments from source code (C or C++ or something like that)?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241327/python-snippet-to-remove-c-and-c-comments and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394017/remove-comments-from-c-c-code. You probably won't find a solution with just the plain `cmd` tools, the problem is more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say cmd isn't efficient enough to do that. Try python or some other a-bit-higher-language.