# Pycparser failed on comments

Tags: python, c, pycparser

When I'm trying to use `pycparser` to parse files with comments I got ParseError

```
import pycparser
parser = pycparser.CParser()
parser.parse("int main(void){return 0;}")
parser.parse("/* comment */ int main(void){return 0;}")


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_pycparser.py", line 18, in <module> parser.parse("/* comment */ int main(void){return 0;}")
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 124, in parse
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 265, in parse
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 1047, in parseopt_notrack
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 1423, in p_error
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pycparser\plyparser.py", line 54, in _parse_error
pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: :1:1: before: /
```

**Solution**: `pycparser` in current version doesn't support comments in source code, but [this fork](https://bitbucket.org/barel/pycparser/commits/branch/default) allow it, or you can use recipe from question [Python snippet to remove C and C++ comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241327/python-snippet-to-remove-c-and-c-comments) to remove comments from source code.

```
import pycparser
import re
def comment_remover(text):
    def replacer(match):
        s = match.group(0)
        if s.startswith('/'):
            return ""
        else:
            return s
    pattern = re.compile(
        r'//.*?$|/\*.*?\*/|\'(?:\\.|[^\\\'])*\'|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"',
        re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE
    )
    return re.sub(pattern, replacer, text)

parser = pycparser.CParser(keep_comment=True)
parser.parse("int main(void){return 0;}")
parser.parse("/* comment */ int main(void){return 0;}")
parser_2 = pycparser.CParser()
parser.parse(comment_remover("/* comment */ int main(void){return 0;}"))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, pycparser does not parse comments, or anything related to the C preprocessor (in a regular C compiler, the preprocessor strips comments before the compiler sees them).

To stop comments from messing your parsing, run the code through the preprocessor first, as suggested in the pycparser `README`. To actually meaningfully parse comments (and get their contents), pycparser is not the right tool, unfortunately.